# SQL / SSRS Expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am working on a report which is an invoice. The line item numbers on the invoice start at one and increment based on the count of the item purchased. For example, the first line in the invoice will always be 1. The first line contained the item and the count of two, therefore the next line number will be three, and so on. I have been successful in creating part of this and it fails on the last line. The problem is the last line number is incrementing to include the line number and the count of items on the last line.

[image: Text]

The final line number should be 7 which would be an accumulation of the count to that point. However, I don't seem to be able to get there.

I have tried running total and that did not work. I wrote a case statement that gets me to the last line.

```
WITH INVOICE AS (
Select Row_Number() Over (Order By ProdNo) RowNum, Count(ProdNo) As Count, ProdNo
From Orders Where OrderNo = @OrderNo
Group By ProdNo)

   Select 
   *, 
   Case 
     WHEN RowNum = '1' THEN '1'
     WHEN RowNum = '2' THEN LAG(RowNum,1,0) OVER (Order By ProdNo) + LAG(Count,1,0) OVER (Order By ProdNo)
     WHEN RowNum > '2' THE SUM(COUNT) Over(Order By ProdNo)
     End As LineNo
     From INVOICE Order By ProdNo
```

Any thoughts?

```
Scripts to create the table and insert data:

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
       [OrderNo] [int] NULL,
       [ProdNo] [int] NULL
       ) ON [PRIMARY]
       GO

    Insert Into Orders (OrderNo, ProdNo)
 
   Values ('001', '50822'), ('001', '50822'), ('001', '50899'), ('001', '50899'), ('001', '50899'),
       ('001', '53066'), ('001', '60936'), ('001', '60936'), ('001', '60936'), ('001', '60936'),
       ('001', '60936'), ('001', '60936'), ('001', '60936')
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very inelegant way of doing it but it works

```
SELECT z.*
    , ln = sum(prvCount) over(order by sort) + 1
     FROM 
(
SELECT 
    o.*
    , prvCount = LAG(Count,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY sort)
    FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        o.ProdNo
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ProdNo) as sort
        , [Count] =  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ProdNo)
    FROM Orders o 
    WHERE OrderNo = @OrderNo
    ) o
     )     z
```

Comment: Elegant or not that was bang on! Thank you. I really appreciate this.

Comment: No problem. Could you please mark the answer as accepted.